# Not able to get zero if data is not present in database for month

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I am trying to get data from database based on Month for Last 12 Year. I able to get the data monthwise and trying to get "0" if data is not present in any specific month.
Below is the code. I am new to Laravel and self learner. Your help really appreciated

Controller Code

```
 $results        =   Dairyexpense::select(
                                        DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(expensesdate, "%M %Y") as "month_name", SUM(amount) as "amount", max(expensesdate) as expensesdate')
                                        )
                                        ->whereBetween('expensesdate', [$start_date, $end_date])
                                        ->groupBy('month_name')
                                        ->orderBy('expensesdate', 'desc')
                                        ->get()
                                        ->keyBy('month_name')
                                        ->map(function ($item) {
                                            $item->date = Carbon::parse($item->date);
                                            return $item;
                                        });

                $start    = new DateTime($start_date);
                $end      = new DateTime($end_date);
                
                $interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
                $period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

                $rr = array_map(function ($datePeriod) use ($results) {
                    $date = $datePeriod->format('Y-m-d');
                    return $results->has($date) ? $results->get($date)->total : 0;
                
                }, iterator_to_array($period));
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a different date format here

```
$date = $datePeriod->format('Y-m-d');
```

Like this ('F Y')

Comment: Thanks... its showing value but "Null". DId i miss something as not showing the amount

Comment: Thanks it working now, i made some changes..

Answer (score 0):

```
$results = Dairyexpense::whereBetween('expensesdate', [$start_date, $end_date])
           ->groupBy('expensesdate')
           ->orderBy('expensesdate')
           ->get([
               DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(expensesdate, "%M %Y") as expensesdate'),
               DB::raw('SUM(amount) as total')
           ])
           ->keyBy('expensesdate')
           ->map(function ($item) {
               $item->date = Carbon::parse($item->date);
               return $item;
           });
         
$start = new DateTime($start_date);
$end = new DateTime($end_date);

$interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

$rr = array_map(function ($datePeriod) use ($results) {
    $date = $datePeriod->format('F Y');
    return $results->has($date) ? $results->get($date)->total : 0;
}, iterator_to_array($period));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).